# Xamarin Android app is crashing when installed from the store

Tags: android, xamarin

I have created an application which is using webservices, qrcode scanning ( zing).

When I run my app in debug mode everything is working fine.

Also when those apk files are sideloaded on different devices everything is fine.

The release version is publish and signed though  Ad-Hoc and saved to disk. side loading this file also works fine.

I have uploaded the file to the PlayStore to debug and test the application prior to delivering to the customer, but when the app is installed through the Playstore, the app crashes directly after the splashscreen.

looking at the reports which are generated for me by android I really have no clue where to look for my solution.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/jfltexx/jflte:5.0.1/LRX22C/I9505XXUHOB7:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 21093, tid: 21163, name: Thread-73837 >>> mobilesr.mobilesr <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
 r0 00000000 r1 00000000 r2 00001002 r3 00000000
 r4 af4cf020 r5 00000000 r6 00000000 r7 b4dfac70
 r8 b6ef9e04 r9 b4e69300 sl b46eaca0 fp b4e4f1c0
 ip b4dfaca0 sp b46eac28 lr b4ba60e8 pc b6ea1464 cpsr 60070030

backtrace:
 #00 pc 00011464 /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+83)
 #01 pc 000a40e4 /system/lib/libart.so (std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<< <std::__1::char_traits<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)+44)
 #02 pc 0022dd03 /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Attach(char const*, bool, _jobject*, bool)+338)
 #03 pc 00218089 /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::AttachCurrentThread(char const*, bool, _jobject*, bool)+12)
 #04 pc 001b242b /system/lib/libart.so (art::JII::AttachCurrentThread(_JavaVM*, _JNIEnv**, void*)+190)
 #05 pc 00009774 /data/app/mobilesr.mobilesr-1/lib/arm/libmonodroid.so
```

Does anybody has some thoughts on where I have to look for the solution?

I need to get this version working in the store.

greetings,

Comment: Connect to logcat and view the data it dumps out as you're starting up the application. It should provide some more insights... Could you also include the logcat output into the question so others can analyse it?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the info, I'll keep it in mind for future debugging sessions. 
About the app, yesterday evening, directly after uploading and publishing the new APK, the system kept crashing with the report as shown above, this morning, everything was working fine, the app is completely functioning from within the store.

I don't know, but I think it's a time issue. installing the app directly after publishing it through pushing it to the app, might result in a broken version because it's not completely ready yet or some like that. It could also be some kind of check from the system back to the store and because it can't be found yet the app is halted.

anyway, for me the app is working, so at this moment I'm happy.

Greetings,